# How do you hide columns in the API Platform Admin?

Tags: api-platform.com

I have the API Platform setup with a few roles and serialization groups that return the correct data for those groups.

In the React Admin though, while the data is (correctly) not returned in the *JSON* response from the *GET* call for a collection or item, the column is still displayed in the admin, just with no data.

Therefore, is there any way to hide those columns in the admin via an annotation or config option?

Example: I create a serialization group called "show_this" in which in include the fields `accountNumber` and `routing`.  I don't include the field that I want to hide, let's say it's called `secretCode`.

In the JSON I get back from the endpoint it returns

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "accountNumber": "12345678",
 "routing": "123456"
}
```

and, quite rightly, doesn't include the "secretCode" field.

However, on the Admin I get columns

```
id | Account Number | Routing | Secret Code
 1 | 12345678       | 123456  |
```

where the Secret Code is always blank

I would, of course, want the Secret Code column not to appear at all.

```
id | Account Number | Routing
 1 | 12345678       | 123456
```

Comment: Unfortunatly the jsonld documentation contains all the fields not only those serialized. I would also like to know if there's a way to remove any reference to those fields from the hydra documentation completly but I have not had any luck so far